# NUnit test properties not accessible in parametrized tests

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

Originally encountered when using `TestCaseSource` and custom derived property attribute. Here's a distilled example:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SomeTestFixture
{
    [Test, Property("SomeProperty", "foo")]
    public void RegularTest()
    {
    }

    [Test, Property("SomeProperty", "foo"), TestCase(0)]
    public void ParametrizedTest(int x)
    {
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        var properties = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties;
    }
}
```

`properties` will have "SomeProperty": "foo" when tearing down after RegularTest, but they'll be empty after ParametrizedTest. Why is that the case, and how can I work around it other than using reflection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a feature of NUnit that properties set on a **parameterized** test apply to the suite that contains the individual test cases. Therefore, you should not apply properties in that way unless you want them to be properties of the suite, and not the test cases.

This might be a design flaw, of course. At minimum, it's confusing to users.

If you specify a test case with `TestCaseAttribute` you cannot add a new property although you can specify some well-known properties like description. The workaround is to use `TestCaseSourceAttribute` to specify the cases and provide individual instances of `TestCaseData` for each case. The `TestCaseData` class does allow you to set a property on each case.

Admittedly, this isn't very convenient, but it is a workaround.